# Photoshop layers are there but I can't see anything

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I've spent all night working on this layout for a client and I'm 100% sure I saved my work — every 5-10 seconds of work I save.

That said. I open up Photoshop today to get some work done I notice that although my layers are there and named, they don't show on the document/canvas.

For example, if I have a text layer with red text, I select the layer and the color thing above in the property pane turns to the colors I gave all my headers — but the actual content (the text in this case) is nowhere on the page.

Keeping on with the troubleshooting, I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> so I can see the whole document. Then I mouse over one of the layers layers that is acting weird, I mouse over the layer thumbnail, I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click it so that it can auto select the content on that layers and again, nothing.

Any ideas as to what could be happening?

Comment: Does the appropriate image appear in the layer's thumbnail?  When you hit `Ctrl + T`, does *any* bounding box show up (even off of the image canvas)?

Comment: I'm guessing that you have an opaque layer at the top which is hiding everything behind it.  Have you tried hiding all the layers and then unhiding them one at a time?

Comment: @paranoid, yes i hid ALL the layers and one by one went turning them on/off and nothing. @ breakthrough, yeah no bounding box comes up. ive never had a problem like this b4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be caused by bugs in your graphics card driver. Go to Preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) → Performance and uncheck the "Enable GPU" option to see of that would help.

Updating the driver may also work.

Answer (score 3):

Check if layer filter is not activated (the little red square).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you use by any chance the "timeline" to create a gif?

I had the same problem. The layers were there but showed white on the canvas. Try opening the timeline option.

Go to Window > Timeline to open the Timeline panel.

Hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, even "Select Pixels" showed the outline in place, and no layer was above it. It turned out, the layer's opacity had been set to 0% for some reason... Not sure why I would have done that (or if I hit some shortcut by accident that caused it?), but bringing opacity back to 100% worked for my particular case.

Answer (score 0):

-> Windows
-> Workspace
 -> Reset Pallette Location

I was trying to edit some text but my layer text was gone. The reset palette location brought all my layers back to the canvas. I must have accidentally turned layers off somehow.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Answer (score 0):

In the layers box, the Red button is a toggle which hides and displays layers. Try clicking it if your layers have disappeared:

[image: Red layer toggle button in photoshop]

Comment: Why was this down voted? I'm not a Photoshop expert but this seems legitimate?